# Infinite counter loop to be delay for ever 37 second in php

Tags: php

I have infinite counter loop here is my link https://projectjeet.in/beta9/

i want a counter loop to be delay ever 37 second here is my code

```
$start = strtotime("2019-04-15 12:05") + -12350308;
echo time()-$start;
```

please note that the last digit ie(8) should delay for 37 seconds ex:-12350308

Answer (score 0):

Best way to delay in PHP by using sleep() function.

> **Solution 1**

```
<?php
<?php

     $start = strtotime("2019-04-15 12:05") + -12350308;

     sleep(37);

     echo time() - $start;
?>
```

> **OUTPUT**

12:44:47

12:44:52

---

> **Solution 2**

You can substract seconds from the current time.

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date) - 37);
```

Comment: my question is that i want the last digit(i,e,7) 54148567 to be delay 37 seconds

Comment: @nsing if you delay whole last number(54148567) then it ultimately delay last digit(8).

Comment: sir what happen is that it works like 54148567,54148568,54148569 but my required ment is that it should work like 54148567,54148578,here the last two digit should be change after  every 37 seconds

Comment: Yes, That will `sleep()` function will do. Sleep() function will sleeps for the seconds and then it will attend the seconds. Just try sleep(5) and then refresh the page you will see that time will sleep for 5 seconds . I have updated my answer